# How to delete a GitHub repository added with "Import Repository"

Tags: github

Quick question, I added a new repository by selecting **import repository** in my GitHub account. I entered the requested url link under header **Your old repository’s clone URL**, however the import did not complete, error message: "No source repositories were detected at *url://abc.com/username/xyz.git*. Please check the URL and try again.", (where abc is the version control name, and xyz is the repository name. Hence no single file was uploaded to the account. Changing the repository only creates a new one (as it probably should), which isn't what I'm looking for.

I no longer want to import the cloned repository, I just want to delete the created, empty repository from my list of existing repositories. When I click on it to go to "settings" and delete it the usual way, the page redirects to the "import repository" page.

Any tips on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Strange...could you post some screenshots?

Comment: @Hcaernit I tried while compiling the question and StackOverflow said I needed to acquire "points" to a certain level to qualify for that. So I tried elaborating the issue through text instead.

Comment: Solved this by creating a new repository and entering the new repo URL on the page 'import a repository' in the section requesting to enter '...old repository’s clone URL'. After closing the red warning text at the top of the page, the 'begin import' button is activated again. Then it's a simple Settings--> Delete repository as usual.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean: By entering a valid public and cloneable URL that is different from the original one that failed, the cancel button becomes available. When clicking the cancel button, it directs you back to the main repository screen where you can delete it. Thanks!